tradingview-lightweight-android apis not getting updated
I have a page in jetpack-compose in which I show a financial chart, using tradingview-lightweightchart-android library(which is just a wrapper around webview and tradingview-lightweight-chart). The thing is that i want to flip between area and candle charts.
Now the problem is that this shows both area and candle charts stacked on each other and when reaches the log lines that will output the areaAPI and candleAPI, it shows them both null.
So this is how I implement it:
@Composable 
fun ChartView(...){
    var areaAPI: SeriesApi? = remember {
        null
    }


    var candleAPI: SeriesApi? = remember{
        null
    }

    val context = LocalContext.current


    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(271.dp)
            .padding(end = horizontalPadding)
    ){

        val candleStickOptions = CandlestickSeriesOptions(...)
        val areaOptions = AreaSeriesOptions(...)
        AndroidView(
            factory = {
                ChartsView(context = it).apply {
                    api.applyOptions {
                        ...
                       
                        api.addAreaSeries(
                            options = areaOptions,
                            onSeriesCreated = { api ->
                                    api.setData(priceAreaData())
                                    areaAPI = api
                            })

                        api.addCandlestickSeries(
                            options = candleStickOptions
                        ) { api ->
                                api.setData(priceCandleData())
                                candleAPI = api
                        }
                        }//end of applyOptions
            }//end of factory,
            update = {

                chart.apply {

                    if(shouldShowAreaChart){
                        
                                    Log.d(TAG, "ChartView update: candle api: $candleAPI")
                                    candleAPI?.applyOptions(candleStickOptions.copy(visible = false))
                                    areaAPI?.applyOptions(areaOptions.copy(visible = true))
                                    areaAPI?.setData(provideProperData)

                    } else {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "ChartView update: area api: $areaAPI")
                                    areaAPI?.applyOptions(areaOptions.copy(visible = false))

                                    candleAPI?.applyOptions(candleStickOptions.copy(visible = true))
                                    candleAPI?.setData(priceCandleData())

                    }

                }

            }//end of update
        )//end of AndroidView
     }//endOfBox
}


Hi! Did you find solution? I've same problem too)

After a lot of trials, I had to create a class that inherits ChartsView and stored the apis in that class.

Yeah, so did I)
